# How to make a discord bot command using python which will make another bot do something

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a bot which will make my other bot do something but i haven't Really Found Out A Way To Do It Can Someone Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They work just like normal commands. The only issue is that most bots don't listen to other bots to avoid abuse.

If, however, you have a bot of which you know it *does* listen to bots, you can just send a message like you would normally do. A command that makes your bot send `<other-bot's-prefix><command_name> <args>` will work just fine.

```py
@client.command()
async def dosmth(ctx, command):
    await ctx.send(f"{other-bots-prefix}{command}")
```

For example, if you would want to use another bot's command called `ping`, it would become `<your-bot's-prefix>dosmth ping`.

EDIT:

Put an `await client.process_commands()` at the bottom of your second bot's `on_message` to make it respond to bots as well. Be careful about possible side effects tho (other bots triggering it, ...).

```py
@client.event()
async def on_message(message):
    ...
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: I Also Own The 2nd Bot So Its Not A Problem I Want The Command To Be Of The 1st Bot And The First Bot Doing Something And After That The 2nd Bot Will Do Something

Comment: And I Basically Mean A `client.run(token1, token2)`

Comment: Edited my response, that's how you make your other bot respond to it. Not sure why you'd run the exact same bot twice with different tokens tho, I don't see the use in that.